# Why can't Fabric fabfile see Django settings?

Tags: django, fabric

I have a minimal Django project that contains a fabfile that simply tries to display a Django setting:

```
# fabfile.py
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib import django

django.settings_module('conf.settings')
from django.conf import settings

def set():
    print settings.DEBUG
```

When I run activate my virtual environment 'venv' on my local host, go to the project directory '/www/django/testfab/' and run the command 'fab set', I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/smith/venv/django18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 743, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/Users/smith/venv/django18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 427, in execute
    results['<local-only>'] = task.run(*args, **new_kwargs)
  File "/Users/smith/venv/django18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/www/django/testfab/fabfile.py", line 8, in set
    print settings.DEBUG
  File "/Users/smith/venv/django18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/smith/venv/django18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/smith/venv/django18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named conf.settings
```

My settings.py file is in my /www/django/testfab/conf directory:

```
.
├── conf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── fabfile.py
├── fabfile.pyc
└── manage.py
```

My DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable is set to 'conf.settings'.

Why is Fabric not seeing my settings.py file?  I'm following the [Django Integration](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/contrib/django.html) instructions as shown in the Fabric documentation.

Thanks!

### **SOLUTION**

As Sean Hayes points out below, this is a Fabric [issue](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/256). Here's how to get around it:

```
django.settings_module('conf.settings')
from django.conf import settings
_ = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What directory are you running `fab` from? `conf` won't be recognized as a Python module unless `/www/django/testfab/` is on the Python path. Running `fab` or `python` or `./manage.py` from that directory will add it to the Python path during that command's execution.

It's also possible that `conf.settings` is raising it's own `ImportError`.

Comment: I'm running fab from the top-level /www/django/testfab directory.  It's unlikely that conf.settings is raising an error as I haven't made any changes to the file that was created when I created the project.  Also, I can start the Django dev web server.  If there were an error in the settings file, I'd think I would be prevented from running the server.

Comment: I just tried your code locally and got the same error. What's weird is if I add an ipdb statement at the module level and call `foo()` (I renamed `set` to `foo` since `set` is a keyword), it returns fine, and the `foo` returns fine. It only throws an error if `settings.DEBUG` is first accessed inside a running Fabric task.

Comment: Found the error. Inside the `foo` task, the sys.path is different. Must be a Fabric bug.

Comment: Thank you Sean!  Yes, this appears to be a Fabric issue.  I'll post a solution described in that issues thread so others will know how to get around this problem.